# Why does grpc-gateway is not building new endpoints

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-gateway

When I try to generate a proxy file via **go build -o ./out/grpc-proxy**, the proxy is generating without the new endpoints added in proto files

I use node.js (v10.16.3) and grpc/go after that I build grpc-proxy.

Generating code from *.proto into *.pb.go, *.pb.gw.go, *.swagger.json via **protoc**

Then patching it with **sed**, after that building via **go build -o path**

Did the same as [here](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway)

Comment: Can you post a complete example with commands you use to define and build your proto files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the import of the project files in the main.go file was related to git and not to the project on the local computer.